# Processing array to regenerate new array

Tags: php, arrays

I make a call to an API and receive a JSON response which I then decode into an Array.  The data I end up with is something like the following

```
Array
(
    [_id] => aasdasdasdasdasd
    [created] => 2017-01-16T14:11:54.616Z
    [options] => Array
        (
            [title] => 1
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [labelName] =>  Date
                            [labelValues] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => March 2016
                                )

                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [labelName] => Title
                            [labelValues] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Food
                                )

                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [labelName] => Product
                            [labelValues] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Rice
                                )

                        )

                )

        )
)
```

Because I am doing this in a loop, I receive many responses like the above.  My aim is to extract the values from labelValues so I can create a folder structure.

Essentially, the above will generate an image, and for the above example the image should be placed in the following directory structure

> 2016 > Food > Rice > the generated image

I can handle creating the folder structure, but first I need to place the above data into an array.  I would expect the array to look something like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Date] => 2016
            [Title] => Food
            [Product] => Rice
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Date] => second_loop_date
            [Title] => second_loop_title
            [Product] => second_loop_product
        )
    ...
)
```

I have been trying to take it step by step to get the desired output, and I have been print things in order to debug along the way.  I am sure there is a more effecient way compared to what I have done, but so far I have something like this

```
foreach ($output['options'] as $key => $value) {
    if($key == 'data') {
        foreach ($value as $label) {
            foreach ($label as  $labelValue) {
                foreach($labelValue as $output) {
                    print_r("<pre>");
                    print_r($output);
                    print_r("</pre>");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This kind of gets me to the values, but I also get a lot of warnings like

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 43

So really I was wondering what the best way to create this array would be.  I have seen array_search, but not too sure if I can use it in this situation?

Any advice appreciated

Comment: My guess would be the problem is that you're declaring `$output` twice - you start the `foreach` on `$output`, then later you loop through `$labelValue as $output`. Change the second `$output` to something like `$labelValueOutput`.

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake, had updated in the original code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you a little bit complicate your code. You can access directly
`$output['options']['data']` and it let you remove two outer loops.

```
$results = array();
foreach ($output['options']['data'] as $data) {
    if (isset($data['labelValues'][0])) {
        $results[$data['labelName']] = $data['labelValues'][0];
    }
}
```

**Note**: I simplified accessing `labelValues`, because it looks form your example array, that there is always only one item. In other case, you should use your inner loop to iterate over all `labelValues` and concatenate them into one string perhaps.

Comment: Perfect, I thought I was over complicating it, and once you start getting into all them loops it gets a bit confusing.  Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 1):

Your current loop seems a little bit complicated..

The error occurs because you want to iterate over an string(labelName), which isn't possible.

Transform your current loop to a working one, should look like this:

```
foreach ($output['options']['data'] as $item) {
    print_r("<pre>");
    print_r($item['labelValues'][0]);
    print_r("</pre>");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution using `array_column` and `array_combine` functions:

```
...
$result = array_combine(
    array_column($output['options']['data'], 'labelName'),
    array_column(array_column($output['options']['data'], 'labelValues'), 0)
);

print_r($result);
```